# Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk!

Tags: android, android-support-library

Заголовок гуглила. Дела все как написано. Вот результат:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут два варианта:

1) Вы не поставили галочку на copy project into work space когда импортировали библиотеку android-support-v7-appcompat, поэтому попробуйте повторить все поставив галочку

2) Второй вариант описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18548129)